# Filter out null string in a list of lists

Tags: list, function, haskell, filter

Currently I have this function:

```
removeNull strList = filter (not . null) strList
```

But I need to use map (I assume) to apply it to a list of lists, but I'm getting type errors.

In GHCi, the functions filters this correctly:

```
removeNull ["i", "", "b"]
["i","b"]
```

But this doesn't filter:

```
removeNull [["i", "", "b"], ["i", "", "b"]]
[["i","","b"],["i","","b"]]
```

Comment: `fmap removeNull [[..]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to apply your filter to each subList, e.g.

```
removeNull strList = map (filter (not . null))  strList
                   //^^^ See here
```